Invalid JWT Signature from JWT.IO JWT token from ASP.NET Core Web API
I am doing a POC. My key is working with the ASP.NET Web API. I'm trying to use the same key in ASP.NET Core Web API:
"Key": "ERMN05OPLoDvbTTa/QkqLNMI7cPLguaRyHzyg7n5qNBVjQmtBhz4SzYh4NBVCXi3KJHlSXKP+oi2+bXr6CUYTR=="


This is the ASP.NET Core Web API token creation code:

Now, going to swagger to see the response body.
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9lbWFpbGFkZHJlc3MiOiJ1ckBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJBZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTcxMzAyNDgwMCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo1MTU5LyIsImF1ZCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NDIwMC8ifQ.LhAtW-g6WiIk_gwRVkXwyrS1KaGo7RGQDOLzas0Vdx4



Same in Angular too:

Angular Client
public userlogin(email: string, password: string):Promise<{StatusCode:number,StatusDescription:string}> {    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.httpClient.post<any>(this.baseUrl + '/'+this.controllerName+'/' + email + '/' + password + '/StudentLogin',{})
        .subscribe((response) => {
          if(response.StatusCode===200)
          {
            this.loggedIn = true;
            this.Username=email;
            this.userLoggedIn.next(this.loggedIn);
            //this.UserEmail.next(this.Username);
            
            this.setToken(response.StatusDescription);
          }
          else{
            this.Username='';
            this.loggedIn=false;
          }          
          resolve(response); // Resolve with the response data
        });
    });

Any help appreciated

How is the client parsing the response? can you show the code where its parsing the response

Here is the Angular checking it . But it is not coming. console is showing the error.

There's nothing wrong with the token, and it can be verified on jwt.io with the given key. You didn't provide the key in the input field in the right column under VERIFY SIGNATURE. Without knowing the key, jwt.io can't verify the signature. I have desribed in my answer here how to do it correctly and avoid false verification.

@jps,Then Why My Angular app is throwing Error Syntax error E Unexpected token  in console.

I have fixed this issue. IactionResult is not returning the string. thats what .subscribe((response) throwing an exception in console.Log.
